# Im new to joomla and lost. I have this joomla template i downloaded for testing purposes, how do i integrate it

Tags: templates, joomla

Like the question states, im new too joomla, just installed 1.6 on my local xampp server, and after install, i launch joomla from local server, it asks for login info, and the it just shows joomla's left hand navigation bar.  So my question is, how do i integrate an existing joomla template to my local joomla setup?

Answer (score 1):

Login to the backend by going to mysite.com/administrator (replace mysite.com with your domain name), and then type in your login information. After you are logged in, click 'Extension Manager', or go under the 'Extensions' dropdown menu and click on 'Extension Manager'. Click on 'Choose File', and browse to your template. Click 'OK', then click 'Upload & Install'. After you do this, you should be able to see your template by clicking 'View Site' in the top-right of your screen.